# What is wrong with this concatenate statement?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

I'm working with a MySQL server `Server version: 5.6.42-cll-lve - MySQL Community Server (GPL)` and I'm having some major issues with CONCAT()

```
       public function get_urls() {
        // Create query
        $query = "SELECT a.Name, a.PrimaryVersion, e1.URL
        FROM " . $this->table . " a
        INNER JOIN
        FunnelsFlows b ON a.Funnel_ID = b.Funnel_ID
        INNER JOIN
        BackendFlows c ON b.BackendFlow_ID = c.BackendFlow_ID
        INNER JOIN
        BackendLevels d ON CONCAT(c.Level, :lv) = d.BackendLevel_ID
        LEFT JOIN
        BackendPages e1 ON d.Upsell = e1.BackendPage_ID
        LEFT JOIN
        BackendPages e2 ON d.Downsell1 = e2.BackendPage_ID
        LEFT JOIN
        BackendPages e3 ON d.Downsell2 = e3.BackendPage_ID
        WHERE                    
        a.Funnel_ID = :fid 
        LIMIT 0,1";
        // Prepare statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        // Bind ID
        $stmt->bindParam(':fid', $this->fid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':lv', $this->lv, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        // Execute query
        $stmt->execute();
```

Running this code throws the following error: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'c.Level' in 'on clause' in ...`

The entire database structure you can view here:
https://app.sqldbm.com/MySQL/Share/wBAF2JMRFFSoPPjIPdYZc0GFrngIE8md_DYjF4jNYw0

Comment: `CONCAT` works as expected, but your SQL does not.

Comment: Don't quote parameters, don't quote identifiers or use backticks on each ``(`a`.`Level`, :level)``

Comment: @PM77-1 Absolutely, as per my post "I've narrowed it down to an issue with how I'm using concat probably". The tools are there and they work fine, I'm just having an issue using them

Comment: Ok, now we need `SHOW CREATE TABLE BackendFlows;`  I guess the foreign key column name is something like `Level_ID`. If so, Q can be closed/deleted due to typo only.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone https://app.sqldbm.com/MySQL/Share/wBAF2JMRFFSoPPjIPdYZc0GFrngIE8md_DYjF4jNYw0 You can view the whole DB here

Comment: This cannot work like that. What is the meaning of the column `BackendFlows.Levels`?

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone That's for a completely different functionality. A backend flow can have 0-10 levels, that column is meant to be a frontend generated number of levels when each row is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query cannot work like that. You are trying to concat a field content `CONCAT(c.Level, :lv)` with a parameter `:lv`. This results in a string if there were a column `Level`. However, you rather want to build a dynamic column name like `Level1` / `Level2` aso.

Unfortunately this cannot be done by parameters. This is owing to the fact, that query plans are prepared. Changing column names at execution time would alter the query plan.

You either need to build dynamic SQL in such a case or write a complex `ON` clause.

The `ON` clause:

```
ON 
(
  (:lv = 1 AND c.Level1 = d.BackendLevel_ID)
  OR
  (:lv = 2 AND c.Level2 = d.BackendLevel_ID)
  -- and so on
)
```

Dynamic SQL:

```
$sql = 'ON (c.Level' . inval($this->lv) . ' = d.BackendLevel_ID)'
```

Since PHP's `intval` function is considered to be safe, I would prefer the latter example in order to improve SQL performance.

Comment: Unfortunately for me, this is the same answer I came up with. Now to filter the variable to avoid SQL injection. 

I never did figure out why `CONCAT(c.Lev, el1)` output as `c.Lev`, may be impossible as a statement.

Thanks

Comment: @MattB Yes, this is due to the fact, that query plans are prepared. Changing column names at execution time would alter the query plan. So you have the mentioned choice between a more complex condition with some performance cost or the dynamic SQL alternative which is not bad by default. You just have to think twice if it really is secure. `intval` returns the datatype integer, so it isn't only a filter. An integer converted to string never can contain other characters than digits, no matter which encoding attack is tried. In worst case it could fail with an error.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the quotes (both for column name and for the value):

```
CONCAT(a.Level, :level)
```

Also, you use a wrong parameter name:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':level', $this->lv, PDO::PARAM_INT);
//                 ^^^^^
```

Comment: This gives me a PDO error, "Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'c.Level' in 'on clause' in ..."

And that second point was my mistake in making this shortened version of the code, in my version it's all :lv instead of :level

Comment: Why `c`? @MattB

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone The full code is joining 5 tables, and works fine when I'm not trying to concatenate the level number, I'm using a b c d and e for my table aliases. Really the level columns are on table c. I supposed it should have said "a.Level" in that comment

Comment: @Martin So far everything that's been suggested that kind of worked has given me the error: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'c.Level' in 'on clause' in ...`. It seems like for some reason my concat is only outputting the first section of the concat. For example, `CONCAT(a.Le, vel1)` is giving me the error: `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'c.Le' in 'on clause' in ...`

Comment: @MartinHeralecký the full code there's multiple tables, I condensed that here for readability. That is essentially `a.Level`, I got that with your recommendation of `CONCAT(a.Level, :level)` only difference is in my code it's really `c.Level`. Sorry for the confusion there, can't figure out why the concat is ignoring the second parameter.

Comment: @MattB Too much confusion `a.Level`, `c.Level`, `a.Le` ... We cannot discuss 10 different versions of code. please construct a [mcve]  added to your question.

Answer (score -1):

What about this?

```
$query = "SELECT a.Name, b.URL
        FROM " . $this->table . " a
        INNER JOIN
        FunnelsFlows b ON CONCAT(a.Level, ':lv') = b.Level_ID
        WHERE                
        a.Funnel_ID = :fid 
        LIMIT 0,1";
        // Prepare statement
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);
        // Bind ID
        $stmt->bindParam(':fid', $this->fid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':lv', $this->lv, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        // Execute query
        $stmt->execute();
```

That was a quick response, so I'll explain now.

What I'm seeing it that you want to concatenate a table column with a string, right?

First you had a wrong ident `:level` which you are trying to bind with the following statement `$stmt->bindParam(':lv', $this->lv, PDO::PARAM_INT);` so you have to change it with `:lv` or chenge the binding statement to `$stmt->bindParam(':level', $this->lv, PDO::PARAM_INT);`.

Second - while you are trying to concatenate a column you have to remove the quotes so it should be `CONCAT('a.Level',` and if the second operator is a string it should be in single quotes, so the full CONCAT operator should be written as follow `CONCAT(a.Level, ':lv')`

Comment: "Try this" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: That was a quick response, I would made the comment a bit later ... which I have done now. I'm not the best guy in English so it takes some time. I hope this explains why I initially wrote just the statement. If you have to be fully correct you probably have to ask downvoters to explain their vote too? I just see the reason why you voted down, but not the other vote-downs.

Comment: @Reflective Thanks! Unfortunately this didn't work, and to clarify the column "Level" does not exist. Columns "Level1" through "Level10" do, so I figured this was combining strings. See my edit for an update

Comment: I didn't downvote, I just left a comment. Maybe the others will come back and let you know why they downvoted.

Comment: @MattB now I get it :)

Comment: @Reflective Do you have any idea why concat seems to be only outputing the first parameter?

Comment: Yep - change `FunnelsFlows b ON CONCAT('a.Level', ':level') = b.Level_ID` to `FunnelsFlows b ON :lv = b.Level_ID` and set bind to `$stmt->bindParam(':lv', 'a.Level'.$this->lv, PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: @MattB CONCAT outputs a string so it will be treated as string in the JOIN not as a column name i.e. after concat is made this will be the representation of the result `FunnelsFlows b ON 'a.Level1' = b.Level_ID`

Comment: @Reflective Hmm, that's giving me null outputs

Comment: @Reflective I appreciate your help, I thought this was going to be a simple syntax error on my part but it's clear to me I need to replicate this in a way where I can share a simplified version of everything and post a new question.

Comment: The concat won't do the trick in your statement as I've already explained above. You should prepare your column name in the bind operator. No need to ask more questions. You know what to do now. Just execute your SQL with sample values and then compare the result with bind values.